# Stop MySQL generating repeated mysql-relay-bin-****.00000* files

Tags: mysql

MySQL is generating repeated 1KB files with names like:

`mysql-relay-bin-2020@002d12@002d06@002011@003a32@003a44@00200@0020@005bnote@005d@0020c@003a@005cxampp@005cmysql@005cbin@005cmysqld@002eexe@003a@0020ready@0020for@0020connections@002e@000d.000005`

I'm using XAMPP on Windows and the files are being generated in `C:\XAMPP\mysql\data` where the database directories live. From what I've read `mysql-relay-bin-*` files are logs related to master slave or multi-master instances but I haven't knowingly set this up and I can't find any settings referring to it.

How can I debug this and find the cause?

It would be very helpful if I can do this through phpMyAdmin which I'm more familiar with.

`show VARIABLES like '%log%'`

Running this in phpMyAdmin on the localhost server produces the following output, is there anything here that indicates the cause?

```
aria_checkpoint_log_activity    1048576 
aria_log_file_size  1073741824  
aria_log_purge_type immediate   
aria_sync_log_dir   NEWFILE 
back_log    80  
binlog_annotate_row_events  ON  
binlog_cache_size   32768   
binlog_checksum CRC32   
binlog_commit_wait_count    0   
binlog_commit_wait_usec 100000  
binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates OFF 
binlog_file_cache_size  16384   
binlog_format   MIXED   
binlog_optimize_thread_scheduling   ON  
binlog_row_image    FULL    
binlog_stmt_cache_size  32768   
encrypt_binlog  OFF 
expire_logs_days    0   
general_log OFF 
general_log_file    username.log    
gtid_binlog_pos     
gtid_binlog_state       
innodb_encrypt_log  OFF 
innodb_flush_log_at_timeout 1   
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  1   
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF 
innodb_log_buffer_size  8388608 
innodb_log_checksums    ON  
innodb_log_compressed_pages ON  
innodb_log_file_size    5242880 
innodb_log_files_in_group   2   
innodb_log_group_home_dir   C:\XAMPP\mysql\data 
innodb_log_optimize_ddl ON  
innodb_log_write_ahead_size 8192    
innodb_max_undo_log_size    10485760    
innodb_online_alter_log_max_size    134217728   
innodb_scrub_log    OFF 
innodb_scrub_log_speed  256 
innodb_undo_log_truncate    OFF 
innodb_undo_logs    128 
log_bin OFF 
log_bin_basename        
log_bin_compress    OFF 
log_bin_compress_min_len    256 
log_bin_index       
log_bin_trust_function_creators ON  
log_disabled_statements sp  
log_error   .\mysql_error.log   
log_output  FILE    
log_queries_not_using_indexes   OFF 
log_slave_updates   OFF 
log_slow_admin_statements   ON  
log_slow_disabled_statements    sp  
log_slow_filter admin,filesort,filesort_on_disk,filesort_priority_...   
log_slow_rate_limit 1   
log_slow_slave_statements   ON  
log_slow_verbosity      
log_tc_size 24576   
log_warnings    2   
max_binlog_cache_size   18446744073709547520    
max_binlog_size 1073741824  
max_binlog_stmt_cache_size  18446744073709547520    
max_relay_log_size  1073741824  
read_binlog_speed_limit 0   
relay_log       
relay_log_basename      
relay_log_index     
relay_log_info_file relay-log.info  
relay_log_purge ON  
relay_log_recovery  OFF 
relay_log_space_limit   0   
slow_query_log  OFF 
slow_query_log_file username-slow.log   
sql_log_bin ON  
sql_log_off OFF 
sync_binlog 0   
sync_relay_log  10000   
sync_relay_log_info 10000
```

If I run the same query directly on my database it shows the following log.

```
back_log    80  
encrypt_binlog  OFF 
general_log OFF 
innodb_encrypt_log  OFF 
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog  OFF 
innodb_scrub_log    OFF 
relay_log       
slow_query_log  OFF 
sync_binlog 0   
sync_relay_log  10000
```

Comment: Thanks for migrating it for me. It is confusing because there are multiple questions relating to MySQL on StackOverflow that have been answered so it feels like recently StackExchange is trying to be more stringent in what questions it will allow where.

Comment: There are lots of questions about mysql that are programming related and are on topic for SO.

Comment: This one is not programming related and was answered https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796158/is-it-safe-to-delete-replication-relay-bin-files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [back on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59600540/xampp-mysql-failed-to-initialize-multi-master-structures) from which my question had been moved. If it had been left there someone might have pointed me to the answer hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%';
```

It looks like the file name has a `-` that is really a "NON-BREAKING HYPHEN" instead of a regular minus sign.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful, I've edited the question to add the output of SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%log%' but I'm having difficulty finding anything that might be the cause.

Comment: I couldn't find anything last night but I found a similar unresolved question asked here https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,655366,655366 by two users apparently experiencing the same issue.